# Differnce between ClientID and Object ID in Azure's User Managed Identity

Tags: azure, identity

I am unable to understand the difference between Client ID and Object ID of a User managed Identity created in Azure. Find screenshot of an identity created. When should we use ClientID and when should we use Object ID?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Client ID: it's used when configuring authentication mechanisms for your application, such as setting up Azure AD app registrations, configuring OAuth flows, or granting API permissions to the application.

Object ID: You would use the Object ID when granting permissions or assigning access control to the Managed Identity itself. For example, when granting the Managed Identity access to Azure resources or assigning role-based access control (RBAC) roles to the Managed Identity.